Borders generated in PDF Template using Java Apache PdfBox
In the nearest future I will be developing a PDF generating service. It's all about a simple template being filled using data coming from request.
During my research I heard about Apache PDFBox and at the moment I am testing it - looks very handy, but I have some annoying problem - when the PDF is generated it has this strange, gray borders.
I made a research and did not found the way to get rid of them.
My sample DataDTO:
@Data
public class DocumentDataDto {
    private int documentNumber;
    private LocalDate date;
    private String creatorFirstName;
    private String creatorLastName;
}

Sample controller:
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PdfController {
    private final PdfService pdfService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/generatePdf")
    public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> generatePdf(@RequestBody DocumentDataDto data) {
        ByteArrayResource pdf = pdfService.generatePdf(data);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=generated.pdf");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/pdf");

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(pdf.contentLength())
                .body(pdf);
    }
}

Sample service:
@Service
public class PdfService {

    public ByteArrayResource generatePdf(DocumentDataDto data) {
        try {
            ClassPathResource pdfResource = new ClassPathResource("templates/template1.pdf");

            try (InputStream inputStream = pdfResource.getInputStream();
                 PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(inputStream)) {

                PDAcroForm form = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

                if (form != null) {
                    PDField field = form.getField("Text1");
                    if (field != null) {
                        field.setValue(String.valueOf(data.getDocumentNumber()));
                    }

                    field = form.getField("Text2");
                    if (field != null) {
                        field.setValue(String.valueOf(data.getDate()));
                    }

                    field = form.getField("Text3");
                    if (field != null) {
                        field.setValue(data.getCreatorFirstName() + " " + data.getCreatorLastName());
                    }

                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    document.save(byteArrayOutputStream);

                    return new ByteArrayResource(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ByteArrayResource(new byte[0]);
    }
}

*NOTE: The code above is just a sample - I am aware that there should be some exception handling instead of returning empty byte array :) *
My PDF template looks simple as that:
Created using https://www.pdfescape.com
I have tried to remove the styles from AcroForm, as well as making them invisible. Unfortunately, no one of my approaches helped. The final output was always like:
output
I have to admit, that is my first time of creating such a service for PDF.
If you have any advices, please let me know - maybe there are more straight-forward ways to achieve the PDF file filled with pure text?
Much appreciate all help!

Can you share the template file in question?

@bertonBoy If KJ's repro corresponds to your templates, it should suffice to replace the BC value of the  appearance characteristics dictionaries of each field widget by an empty array before setting the value.

You mentioned "tried to remove the styles from AcroForm, as well as making them invisible" but your code doesn't include anything like that.
What exactly did you try?
Can you try calling the following method for your fields?
Depending on your template you might not actually need to call all of those so you need to trial-error a bit here.
private void removeFieldBorders(PDField field) throws IOException {
    for (PDAnnotationWidget widget : field.getWidgets()) {
        widget.setBorderStyle(null);
        widget.setColor(null);
        widget.setHighlightingMode(PDHighlightingMode.NONE);
        PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
        appearance.setBorderColour(null);
        widget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(appearance);
    }
}


I am getting NPE at lines: widget.setColor(null); and appearance.setBorderColour(null);

Try using an empty PDF array instead of null in those instructions.

Whilst it is possible to mess about with field styles it is best they are left at default or else they behave different in different viewers. ALL below are the same form just different viewers.
Red surround is reserved for "Required" (Mandatory) whilst all normal fields are simply a pale blue field.

AVOID confusion such as here


Scale and style of text varies considerably too as appearances are a Reader Function 


Is there a way to make the filled form a raw text pdf, without the borders?

Just to make it clear - you mean I can edit the Template or Filled template?
